# How to program game of Go, Baduk, Weiqi in java

Tags: java, baduk

I am a beginner in java, so I would like to know if there are any java skeletons for the board game of Go.

Answer (score -1):

The basic answer is Yes. You can browse through Senseis Library to find some candidates http://senseis.xmp.net/?GoPlayingPrograms - I would recommend Orego by Peter Drake as an accessible starter.